# how to get the value of a dynamically generated radio button in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

i want to get the value of a dynamically generated radio button in servlet, below is my jsp code

```html
 <c:forEach items="${questions1}" var="quest">
            <tr>
                
                <td>${quest.questions}</td>
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td><input name="${quest.questionId}" type="radio" value="${quest.option1}" />${quest.option1}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="${quest.questionId}" type="radio" value="${quest.option2}" />${quest.option2}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="${quest.questionId}" type="radio" value="${quest.option3}" />${quest.option3}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="${quest.questionId}" type="radio" value="${quest.option4}" />${quest.option4}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="${quest.questionId}" type="radio" value="${quest.correctAns}" />${quest.correctAns}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input name="hcorrectAns" type="hidden" value="${quest.correctAns}" /></td></tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

i have tried using `request.getParameter("quest.questionId");` and `request.getParameter("${quest.questionId}")` it didnt work cos am getting null value. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `request.getParameter("put the actual question ID here")`?

Comment: `request.getParameter(quest.questionId);` , but you need `quest` object for that..

Comment: sorry am a little bit confused, how do i create quest object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.getParameterNames()` firstly to get all Parameter Names that are coming in `request` argument.

```
Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
```

Then you can iterate through it to get values of all those parameters.

```
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
    String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
    if (paramValues.length == 1) {
        String paramValue = paramValues[0];
        if (paramValue.length() == 0){
            //No Value;
        }else{
           //You have the value in paramValue);
        }
    else {
        //get all values one by one
        for(int i=0; i<paramValues.length; i++) {
             //get paramValues[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I hope, it will cover all types of dynamically generated *data*.

Comment: thanks for your help, but my issue is that when getting the selected radio button in servlet, it gets null value because of the name of the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<String> params = Collections.list(request.getParameterNames());//Get param name
for (String p: params)
{
  System.out.println(request.getParameter(p));// get param value for each param
}
```